# Gradle build succeeds in local, but builds fail in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

Gradle build succeeds in local, but builds fail in Docker.
The following error occurs during gradle build in docker:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:254)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.incrementalCompilationWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:290)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:213)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:173)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:541)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:387)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:351)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
```

It seems to be caused by the lack of memory in gradle daemon.

My `gradle.properties` is as follows.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx2g
```

My `Dockerfile` is as follows.

```
...
RUN gradlew build -Dspring.profiles.active=${PHASE}
...
```

It's the same gradle memory setting,
**but why does it succeed in local and fail in docker?**

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you try another Java base image to run the test?

Comment: Please, do not post the picture of text, as long as you can post *text* itself.

Comment: Okay, I modified it to text.